# How do I override the Type of members in a base class from the derived class?

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance

I have two classes that know each other in a many-to-many relationship. Now I want to have two additional classes that inherit from the existing classes. The association between the inherited classes should stay.

---

### Example:

Say you have a `Vehicle`

`public class Vehicle{ }`

And you have `Tire`s

`public class Tire { }`

Now you want the `Vehicle` to have many `Tire`s

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Tire[] Tires { get; set; }
}
```

That's great! But a `Truck`s `Tire`s are significantly different than other `Vehicle`s.. They're larger, have spikes (big metal Ramones studs!), are made of space age polymers (plausibly from outer-space) and filled with novel gases (Isn't Neon cool?).

`public class TruckTire : Tire { }`

But here's the rub... my `Truck` now only has normal `Tire`s if it inherits from `Vehicle`...

`public class Truck : Vehicle { }`

### Crux of the problem & question:

So... How do I make it so when people access `Truck.Tires` they get back something that's cast as `TruckTire[]` instead of just regular old `Tire[]` when the `Tires` property/field is defined in the base class with a type of `Tire[]` not `TruckTire[]`? Yes the *instances* at runtime could be `TruckTire`s, but that would require a cast to utilize as such...

Comment: I would strongly suggestion you read Eric Lippert's series of article [Wizard and Warrior](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). It a great explanation on the limit of the type system when enforcing those kind of rules :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TruckTire` is a `Tire` all right so inheritance is appropriate here. `Truck` however cannot use `Tire`s, only `TruckTire`s. This we can achieve by introducing some elementary generics. If the program would need additional types, say `Tractor` and `TractorTire`, the solution could easily be extended to this.

```java
public class Vehicle<T extends Tire> {

    private T[] tires;

    public T[] getTires() {
        return tires;
    }

    public void setTires(T[] tires) {
        this.tires = tires;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (tires == null || tires.length <= 0) {
            return String.format("%s has no tires", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else {
            return String.format("%s has %d tires of type %s", this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    tires.length, tires[0].toString());
        }
    }
}

public class Truck<T extends TruckTire> extends Vehicle<T> {
}

public class Tire {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class TruckTire extends Tire {
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // vehicle
        Vehicle<Tire> vehicle = new Vehicle<>();
        System.out.println(vehicle);
        Tire[] tires = {new Tire(), new Tire(), new Tire(), new Tire()};
        vehicle.setTires(tires);
        System.out.println(vehicle);

        // truck
        Truck<TruckTire> truck = new Truck<>();
        System.out.println(truck);
        TruckTire[] truckTires = {new TruckTire(), new TruckTire(), new TruckTire(), new TruckTire()};
        truck.setTires(truckTires);
        System.out.println(truck);
    }
}
```

**Console ouput:**

```
Vehicle has no tires
Vehicle has 4 tires of type Tire
Truck has no tires
Truck has 4 tires of type TruckTire
```

Comment: Please note, the question has been *significantly* edited from its original. You may wish to revise your answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Could you go a bit into describing your solution? The classic statement is "the whiteboard doesn't have a compiler."  Explaining how the solution works on Programmers.SE is often seen as much more important than any associated code.

Comment: Ok, I've added some explanation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Based on your update from 2015-05-18.**

TruckTire should be a private subclass of Tire. Tire should contain the interface other client classes (Truck, Car) use, and TruckTire encapsulates the behavior. The Truck's interface to TruckTire is the same as Car's interface is to CarTire. They all know them as Tires. Use the [Strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) for Tire.

Comment: @Marc I can point out a concrete LSP violation here: `SuperParent` has a method `addChild(SuperChild)` that accepts anything that inherits from or implements `SuperChild`, including `SuperChild` itself. However, `SubParent` also has a method of the same name, but restricts the argument to be `SubChild`. This means passing a `SuperChild` to `SubParent.addChild($)` is an error. This is an LSP violation unless these two methods are independent of each other (i.e. the `SubParent` method must **hide** the `SuperParent` method).

Comment: Please note, the question has been *significantly* edited from its original. You may wish to revise your answer.

Comment: Also note that every post on Stack Exchange has a detailed edit history that anyone can view for historical purposes, so leaving irrelevant material around for the Google bots to index seems... pointless.